# datetimepicker not passing value to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this input date from the MVC form that I wanted to have the datetimepicker value pass to controller and it is not working.  Not sure what I missed here.

View `add.cshtml`

```
<form id="msform" class="form-inline" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id="txtReviewDate">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('txtReviewDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            defaultDate:new Date()
        });
    });
</script>
 </form>
```

Model

```
public Nullable<DateTime> tempReviewDate
```

Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add (calfreshByWorkUnitID customerinfo)
{
    var vartempReviewDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request["txtReviewDate"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an input that does not have a `name` attribute so it does not submit a value. A form only submits the name/value pairs of its successful form controls.

Change your view to to bind to your model (note I'm assuming the model you have shown is named `calfreshByWorkUnitID`)

```
@model calfreshByWorkUnitID
....
@using (Html.BeginForm(...))
{
    ....
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.tempReviewDate, new { @class="form-control" })
```

Script (attach the plugin to your input)

```
$('#tempReviewDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    defaultDate:new Date()
});
```

and then in the POST method, your model will be correctly bound with the selected date

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add (calfreshByWorkUnitID customerinfo)
{
    // customerinfo.tempReviewDate contains the selected value
```

Comment: Here is the additional syntax for the code  @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.tempReviewDate, new {id="txtReviewDate", @class="form-control", value=Model.tempReviewDate.ToString()})

Comment: NEVER set the value attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. And it already genereate `id="tempReviewDate"` so what is the point of overriding it